# Distance to four

Tags: code-golf, number, natural-language

This challenge is based on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYKn0yUTIU4). I recommend that you watch it before trying this challenge.

First we define a function.  This function ([OEIS](http://oeis.org/A005589)) takes a integer n as input and outputs the number of letters in the English representation of n (without spaces or hyphens).  For example "three" has 5 letters so 3 maps to 5.

As demonstrated in the video starting with any number repeating this process will eventually result in a four, which will map to itself forever.

Here is a crude directed graph showing the orbits of the numbers less than 16:

```
  12 11
    \|      
15 2 6 1 10 14 13
  \ \|/ /  /  /
   7 3-/  8--/
    \|   /
 9 0 5--/
  \ \|
   \-4
```

Your challenge is to determine the number of steps that a number will take (or the number of times this function must be applied to a number) before reaching four (i.e. the level on the directed graph pictured).

### Forming english numbers

Here is a brief explanation of how one should form english words for this challenge:

The numbers one through nineteen are:

one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen, seventeen, eighteen, nineteen

For numbers greater than nineteen the process is as follows:

If the number has a hundreds place begin with the name of digit in the hundreds place and "hundred".

e.g.

```
100 -> "onehundred"
```

If the remainder is less than twenty append the remainder's English representation.

e.g.

```
714 -> "sevenhundredfourteen"
```

Otherwise if the tens digit is not zero append the proper representation:

```
2-> twenty
3-> thirty
4-> forty
5-> fifty
6-> sixty
7-> seventy
8-> eighty
9-> ninety
```

e.g.

```
470 -> "fourhundredseventy"
```

Finally if there is a one's digit append its representation

e.g.

```
681 -> "sixhundredeightyone"
```

### Further Stipulations

- For numbers greater than one hundred you should leave out the "and" when counting the number of letters. For instance 577 is "fivehundredseventyseven" which has 23 letters.
- Your program must accept all integers greater than 0 and less than 1,000 as input via standard methods.
- Your program must output the number of steps required to standard output methods.
- This is codegolf so the solution with the fewest bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
1 -> 3
4 -> 0
7 -> 2
23 -> 5
577 -> 6
600 -> 4
```

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67344/31716) I thought this was a dupe, but I can't find it.

Comment: What happened to "and"? Or rather, why leave out and?!

Comment: @JonathanAllan cuz 'Murica

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 106 bytes

```
f=(n,a="03354435543668877998")=>n-4&&1+f(7*(n>99)-(-a[n/100|0]-(a[n%=100]||a[n%10])-"0066555766"[n/10|0]))
```

Strings seem to be the best way to encode the length, despite the numeric conversion overhead.

Comment: Gosh, that's almost exactly what my (nearly-posted) answer looked like, only 11 bytes shorter.

Comment: @ETHproductions Good thing I golfed 16 bytes off before posting it then!

Answer (score 2):

## Python, with num2words, <s>97 113 115 94 93</s> 92 bytes

+16 bytes (forgot the hyphenation that num2words applies which does not actually change the results of any of the test cases, even though `23` and `577` each have a hyphen)
+2 bytes (forgot to include `f=` although recursive)
-20 bytes (use `re`)
-8 bytes thanks to @Wheat Wizard (use `~`, replace `n!=4` with `n-4`, and ...one line import >_<)
-1 byte thanks to @Cyoce (space from `4 and`)

```
import re,num2words as w
f=lambda n:n-4and-~f(len(re.sub('\W|and','',w.num2words(n))))
```

Just counts up the number of steps; works for huge and negative integers too (`\W` finds the spaces, commas and hyphens in the num2words result):

```
>>> for test in (1,4,7,23,577,600,-1*2**96,3**96):
...     print('test: {0}  ->  {1}'.format(test, f(test)))
...
test: 1  ->  3
test: 4  ->  0
test: 7  ->  2
test: 23  ->  5
test: 577  ->  6
test: 600  ->  4
test: -79228162514264337593543950336  ->  4
test: 6362685441135942358474828762538534230890216321  ->  5
```

Here is that last case, step by step:

```
sixquattuordecillionthreehundredsixtytwotredecillionsixhundredeightyfiveduodecillionfourhundredfortyoneundecilliononehundredthirtyfivedecillionninehundredfortytwononillionthreehundredfiftyeightoctillionfourhundredseventyfourseptillioneighthundredtwentyeightsextillionsevenhundredsixtytwoquintillionfivehundredthirtyeightquadrillionfivehundredthirtyfourtrilliontwohundredthirtybillioneighthundredninetymilliontwohundredsixteenthousthreehundredtwentyone
fourhundredfiftyone
nineteen
eight
five
```

Comment: Don't you need a `f=` before your lambda function

Comment: @WheatWizard I do indeed, and I've done that before!

Comment: If you `import re` and use `re.sub("and|-| ","",num2words(n))` instead of `num2words(n).replace('and','').replace(' ','').replace('-','')` you can save a couple of bytes.

Comment: @WheatWizard I was already doing that :)

Comment: Try `import re,num2words as r` instead of the two different statements.

Comment: `n-4` is the same thing as `n!=4`

Comment: @WheatWizard `num2words` is `w`, `re` is still `re` - note that both the module and function are called `num2words`

Comment: Ok last one, `and 1+` can be replaced with `and-~` to save one byte

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who forgets the `f=` for their recursive lambdas.

Comment: `n-4 and` can become `n-4and`

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 54 bytes

Will try to refactor.

```
KjC"Y©åláóê¤"Ttl.u?<NyT@KNs+V@LKJ_jNT[Z@jC"Ckg"ThtJ7
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=KjC%22%02Y%C2%A9%C3%A5l%C3%A1%C3%B3%C3%AA%C2%A4%22Ttl.u%3F%3CNyT%40KNs%2BV%40LKJ_jNT%5BZ%40jC%22Ckg%14%22ThtJ7&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A4%0A7%0A23%0A577%0A600&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <del>556</del> 295 bytes

Thanks to @KevinCruijssen for saving *261 bytes*

```
  void int(n) {int s[]={0,3,3,5,4,4,3,5,5,4,3,6,6,8,8,7,7,9,9,8,6,9,9,11,10,6,6,5,5,7,7,6};int c=0,t=(int)Math.pow(10,(int)Math.log10(n)),v=1;while(n>0){if(n/100>0)c+=(s[n/100]+7);else {if(n>0&n<25){c+=s[n];break;}else{c+=s[(n/10)+22];}}n=n%t;t=t/10;}while(c!=4){v++;c=s[c];}System.out.print(v);}
```

## Ungolfed:

```
  void int(n) {

    int s[]={0,3,3,5,4,4,3,5,5,4,3,6,6,8,8,7,7,9,9,8,6,9,9,11,10,6,6,5,5,7,7,6};
     int c=0,t=(int)Math.pow(10,(int)Math.log10(n)),v=1;
         while(n>0){
            if(n/100>0)
                c+=(s[n/100]+7);
            else {if(n>0&n<25){
                c+=s[n];
            break;
            }
            else{
                c+=s[(n/10)+22];

            }
            }
            n=n%t;
            t=t/10;
        }

        while(c!=4)
        {
            v++;
        c=s[c];
        }
System.out.print(v);
}
```

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your code, because `s++` isn't possible on a String-array.. :S

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I declare S(counter) as a INT and STRING too....java automatically decide it is an INT.

Comment: Well, if I run your code in ideone or my Eclipse IDE it fails because you have two `s`.. Btw, you can golf your code by quite a large amount like this: `int c(int n){int s[]={0,3,3,5,4,4,3,5,5,4,3,6,6,8,8,7,7,9,8,8,6,9,9,11,10,6,5,5,5,7,6,6},c=0,t=(int)Math.pow(10,(int)Math.log10(n)),x=1;while(n>0)if(n/100>0)c+=s[n/100]+7;else{if(n>0&n<25){c+=s[n];break;}else c+=s[(n/10)+22];}n%=t;t/=10;}for(;c!=4;x++,c=s[c]);return x;}`

Comment: I am shocked......what happen to my code and thanks @KevinCruijssen..and i am correcting it...Thanks again.

Comment: Np :) I think it might be golfed some more somehow without using the if-else and break in there (but I'll leave that to someone else), but your initial code was a great base for tackling the challenge, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 89 bytes

```
Length@FixedPointList[StringLength@StringReplace[IntegerName@#,{" "->"","-"->""}]&,#]-2&
```

Typical Mathematica: built-in functions good, long function names bad. `FixedPointList` applies its first argument (a function) to the second argument repeatedly until the answer doesn't change, listing all results; the results include the original input and two copies of the repeated output, hence the `-2` at the end. Mathematica's built-in `IntegerName` contains spaces and hyphens, so we need to get rid of those by hand.

Annoyingly, `IntegerName`'s output contains the character "‐" (Unicode #8208) rather than normal hyphens; that's why this submission is 89 bytes rather than 88. (And I couldn't precede the code above with four spaces *and* have it accept the Unicode character—any help?—so the above code won't work exactly right if cut and pasted.)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7, <s>344</s> <s>216</s> 208 bytes:

```
x=`input()`;c=0;y=lambda v:dict(zip(range(0,10),[0]+v));l=[3,3,5,4,4,3,5,5,4];d=y(l);e=y([3,6,6,6,5,5,7,7,6]);f=y([i+7for i in l])
while x!='4':x=`sum([q[int(r)]for q,r in zip([d,e,f],x[::-1])])`;c+=1
print c
```

Does not use any external libraries unlike other Python answer. Takes input through `stdin` and outputs to `stdout`.

[Repl.it with All Test Cases!](https://www.repl.it/D4oi)

### Explanation

First creates 3 dictionaries with each one pairing the length of the English word representations of each number to the number it represents in the closed interval `[1,9]` in the ones, tens, and hundreds place, respectively. For example, the first entry in dictionary `d` is `1:3` as `1` is spelled `one` in English and has `3` letters.

Then, each digits place in some string input `x` is assigned to its corresponding dictionary, after which each number in each place is matched up with its value in the corresponding dictionary. For instance, suppose the input number was `23`. The `20` in the tens place would be paired with dictionary `e`, in which it is matched with `6`, and the `3` in the ones place would be paired with dictionary `d`, in which it is matched with `5`. These matched digits are then added together to represent the length of the English representation of the number, which is assigned to `x` as a string and, as long as `x!='4'`, the while loop goes on, incrementing `c` by `1` each time to represent the number of steps taken thus far. Therefore, `23` would correspond to `11`, which would in turn correspond to `6` which would turn to `3` and then to `5` and finally to `4`, resulting in `5` total steps.

Finally, once the loop finishes, `c` is output to `stdout` to represent the "Distance to Four", which in this case would be `5`.